# A combinatorics problem about $n\times n$ square

Tags: combinatorics

In a $n\times n$ square, a **coordinate arrangement** is defined as $n$ cells such that for any row or column, there is only one cell taken. For instance, the arrangement taking the diagonal line is coordinate. Find the largest $k$, such that for any coordinate arrangement, there exist a $k\times k$ square whose cells are all not taken.

I did some experiments on small $n$. For $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$, $k=0,1,1,2,2,2$.

When $n=4$, $k$ should be 1. Thanks to Quang Hoang.

Comment: This is a problem in the latest IMO isn't it? And a small correction: for $n=4$, $k=1$.

Comment: Really? Which year?

Comment: Latest = 2014 :-)

Comment: To Quang Hoang: Thanks!

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be http://oeis.org/A000196 offset by $1$, $\lfloor \sqrt{n-1} \rfloor$ but I don't have a proof.  It seems obvious that it should grow with $\sqrt n$

Comment: IMO problems are posted at http://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx

Comment: @RossMillikan: Why do you think it should grow with $\sqrt n$? Any explain or insight?